# what should i learn for deep learning

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, data-science-model

i have studied the basic of machine learning ,algebra ,statics and probability.now i want start with deep learning for field of image recognition,classification.
i don't know where to start deep learning ,can anyone suggest me where to start and end like syllabus

Comment: Deep learning with Python is a good book. Keras is the thing to go for.

Comment: What about algorithms in deep learning

Comment: Neural nets is deep learning, Keras is the Tensorflow implementation of NN. NN are used for image classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at fast.ai (https://www.fast.ai), only heard the best about it. Supposedly,  it's completely free and easy to get into.

Other often mentioned resources are the course by Andrew Ng (https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning and/or https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) or the (also free) book by Ian Goodfellow (https://www.deeplearningbook.org).